# Javascript syncronous call with update

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have  a function that performs a long task. I would like to create a function that is able to notify the caller of the progress. Ultimately I want to update the UI with the current progress.

Something like this:

```
function myLongMethod(progressCallback)
{
    for(var i = 0 ... )
    {
        progressCallback(i) ;
    }

}
```

This works but updates on UI are not smooth. Is there a better way? I would prefer something with a jquery Deferred object using deferred.notify(). Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with what you wrote ?

Comment: I would suggest a fiddle that reproduces the unwanted effects you're seeing. If it's not possible, try to elaborate on "not smooth".

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. You have got another problem. Javscript always runs on the UI thread. Your operation is blocking this thread (the browser) and you will see some blocking of your browser window. 
Luckily there is a workaround implemented in modern browser called [web workers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers). It's simple just call in your main script another script which then get executed:

```
var w = new Worker("another_script.js");
```

If your worker is ready you can react on the result by adding a event listner to the worker:

```
w.onmessage = function(event) {
  //do something
}
```

When you use this pattern, your UI did not block. You can even return data from a web worker and include scripts into it. More details you can find [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) and [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) is a good starting tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can apply the easing effect to your UI for smoothness and i am giving the following code it may help you

```
var oldProgress = 0;
var uiUpdater = null;
function updateUI(newProgress){         
    if(uiUpdater !=null){
        // update your ui to the old progress first
        window.clearInterval(uiUpdater); // clearing the previous timer
    }        
    var diff = newProgress - oldProgress;
    oldProgress = newProgress;
    var stepSize = diff/5; // applying the new change in 5 steps to the UI
    uiUpdater = window.setInterVal(function(){
       // updating your UI after every 100 milliseconds
       // to give the smoothness
       diff -= stepSize; // decreasing the difference gradually
       if(diff<=0){
           window.clearInterval(uiUpdater); // clearing the interval once the update is done
       } 
    },100);
}
```

You have to call the "**updateUI**" method from you callback with the new progress.